# Downloaded video not shown on Gallery in ionic 4

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3, phonegap-plugins, ionic4

After downloading a image or video file it doesn't shown on gallery, I'm working on ionic 4 tried some media scanner plugin but not working if anyone knows solution help me

```
download(Url, fileName) {
    this.Url = videoUrl;
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();
        const url = this.videoUrl;
        this.file.createDir(ROOT_DIRECTORY, FolderName, true)
            .then((entries) => {
                fileTransfer.download(url, ROOT_DIRECTORY + downloadFolderName + '/videos/' + fileName + '.mp4').then((entry) => {
                    this.presentToast();
                }, (error) => {
                    alert('download error source  ' + error.source);
                    alert('download error target  ' + error.target);
                    alert('upload error code ' + error.code);
                });

            });
    });

}
```

Comment: which plugin you are using to download files?

Comment: filetransfer. i updated the code hav a look at it

Comment: Hey @SnappyToes I am also facing the same issue. Did you find any solution?